# How can I handle logged in users and not logged in users in the same controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Let's say I have a Spring MVC, with Spring Security.  I have a controller method where I want to get at my grandmother's recipes.

```
RequestMapping(value="/Recipe/{recipeId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
Public Recipe getRecipe(@PathVariable("recipeId") int recepieId) {

 Recipe recipe = database.getRecipeById(recepieId);
 if(recipe.isBisket()) {
      return recipe;   
 }

 if(recipe.isSecretCookieRecipe()) {
     boolean isAuthenitacted = Utils.authenticatUser(user);
     if(isAuthenticated() {
          return recipe;
     } else {
          // do something to authenitcate and then return the recipie
     }
  }
}
```

now the problem lies in the Spring security context.  If I do something like this:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/Recipe/*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
```

and

```
<beans:bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">   
   <beans:property name="useReferer" value="true" />
</beans:bean>
```

Now obviously in this scenario, `isAuthenticated()` will always return true as the intercept pattern will handle it. So let me remove the intercept url, and try this REST URL CALL :

```
GET http://bestrecepiesever/Recipe/1
```

Now 1 is a biskett recipe, so anyone can get at it and the call works. Now I want a cookie so I try this:

```
GET http://bestrecepiesever/Recipe/420
```

Now my Utils class will check my session, see that I am not logged it and throw an exception.  And here is where my question lies...  I want to be able to bookmark http://bestrecepiesever/Recipe/420. When I go there I get re-directetd to my login page, I login, I get re-directed back to the recipe.

How do I do this with Spring Security?  What do I put where // do something to authenticate   that will see that I am not authenticated at this time, send me to the login page,  and then back to the recipe.

To complicate things, we have a `SimpleMappingExceptionResolver` that will intercept any and all exceptions and redirect you to a nice your page cannot be found.  And yes, I tried createing my own that redirected to the login page,  which worked, but would not the go back to the referer page.  You can see that SO question here :  [Overriding HandlerExceptionResolver not useing Referer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43397580/overriding-handlerexceptionresolver-not-useing-referer)

**UPDATE**

as per @chaoluo  here is the getAuthentication method in the utils:

```
public static User getUser(IDaoFactory daoFactory) throws Exception {
    String authClass = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal().getClass().getName();
    authClass = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities().getClass().getName();
    if (authClass == null) {
        authClass = "[ unknown ]";
    }

    if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName().toLowerCase().equals("anonymoususer")) {
        throw new Exception("not authorized");
    }
    User theUser = new MyUserDetailsService(daoFactory).loadUserByUsername(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName());
    if (theUser == null) {
        logger.error("Unable to find user in DB for " + SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName());
    }
    return theUser;
}
```

However,  this is completly different from MyAuthenticationProvider  which is used in the SpringSecurity like this:

```
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="myAuthenticationProvider"/>       
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

And the authenticate Method:

```
@Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) 
    throws AuthenticationException 
{
    String username = authentication.getName();
    String password = (String) authentication.getCredentials();
    //System.out.println(org.apache.commons.lang.exception.ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(Throwable));
    IDaoFactory daoFactory = ServiceFactory.getDaoFactory();
    try {
        QadoUserDetailsService userService = new QadoUserDetailsService(daoFactory);
        User user = userService.loadUserByUsername(username);

        if (user == null) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException(BAD_USER);
        }
        if (user.getPassword() == null || user.getSalt() == null || 
            !PasswordEncryption.hashEquals(user.getSalt(), user.getPassword(), password)) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException(BAD_PASSWORD);
        }

        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = user.getAuthorities();
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password, authorities);
    }
    finally {
        daoFactory.cleanup();
    }
}
```

So it there a way to authenticate via the MyAuthenticationProvider inside the controller?

Comment: Could you please post your `Utils.authenticatUser` ? and it needs to do authentication when you set `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY `. Could you please check your question? and Please post your other spring security config, I don't find where you use `authenticationSuccessHandler `.

Answer (score 0):

You are making things to complex. Instead of `@PreAuthorize` use `@PostAuthorize` to do the validation. This will keep your controller clean and let Spring Security handle those things.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/Recipe/{recipeId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@PostAuthorize("returnObject.bisket || (returnObject.secretCookieRecipe && isAuthenticated())")
public Recipe getRecipe(@PathVariable("recipeId") int recepieId) {

 return database.getRecipeById(recepieId);

}
```

Now Spring Security will validate the `returnObject` with the current user.

Comment: But happens when someone adds a pecan pie recipe to the DB?  I don't want to re-write and re-compile each time.

Comment: You have to put the logic somewhere, so you have to recompile something. You could put it in a service and call that from the security expression. Regardless it still has to be somewhere. Also even if that would be added those callbacks for `isBicket` etc. won't cut it either